# Can I lose a curious badge?

Tags: support, badges

Conditions for curious badge are:

> Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and **maintain** a
>   positive question record.

The question is simple - can I lose a curious badge, if I lose my positive question record?

Comment: is this a practical question, or were you just curious ;)

Comment: What do you mean with "practical"? I was **really** interesting in whether I will lost my curious badge if I ask to many questions, which will be down-voted. For me is maintain <=> keep

Comment: sorry, I think my joke was lost in translation - I was making a joke about being 'just curious' as it's the curious badge.

Comment: @Rekshino He/she was only kidding.

Comment: It's OK. Thanks for the clarification! ;) :)

Comment: @Orangesandlemons. Edit your comment with `"just curious"` instead of `just curious` and your joke will works ;)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> The question is simple - can I lose a curious badge, if I lose my positive question record?

The simple answer is **NO,** non-tag badge Badges are never taken away

> can I lose a curious badge

- Regular badges once earned, are not taken away
- Tag badges  are taken away when you no longer meet the criteria,

Comment: I'm not strong in English, but should it not be "and **achieve** a positive question record"

Comment: @Rekshino i think this post will help u https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/is-it-possible-to-lose-badges

Comment: Except documentation badges.. ;)

Comment: @Rekshino The maintain is intended to clarify that you should have a positive question record over those 5 questions, as opposed to achieving the positive question record and then losing it as you ask 4 more awful questions, perhaps replacing maintain with *have* would make sense

Comment: "Tag badges are taken away when you no longer meet the criteria" means that an improper retagging could lose you a badge.